# Pycharm fullscreen across 2 monitors: is this possible?

Tags: pycharm

I am using pycharm, and my code is on the split screen.  When I run debug, the debug/run window pops up and it is very distracting and cramps the amount of code I can look at while debugging...but I would like to keep it up, since I am going back and forth; also, I'd like a fully expanded view of the debug variables...

When I move it to the right, it cramps the screen.  Is there a way for me to stretch pycharm across 2 monitors (Ubuntu 15.10), so that I can place the debug window on the right monitor and the code on the left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, now that I've found the answer, it is kind of trivial.  But I think that it's a cool thing to know is possible, and it currently isn't attached to the search line in the title, so:

Pycharm allows you to view a sub window pinned to the pycharm backdrop as its own window, distinct from the main pycharm window. Just click on the little gear symbol in the upper right corner of the sub-window, and select "windowed mode."  Now, you can just move that window to another desktop.

Comment: Thanks for this.  "Windowed mode" as of 2016.3.2.